# Make `envsubst` fail if a variable is not defined

Tags: environment-variables, gettext

I have a file with a large number of variables in it.

```
$ cat message.txt
Hello, ${LOCATION}! You too, ${PERSON} ;)
```

If `PERSON` is not defined, `envsubst` replaces it with nothing:

```
$ LOCATION=World envsubst < message.txt
Hello, World! You too,  ;)
```

How can I make `envsubst` fail with a non-zero exit code (or something reliable) if any of the many environment variables in the file isn't defined?

Comment: What does it mean **to fail**? What do you want as a result?

Comment: I would like the equivalent of `false`, but I guess I could work with anything reliable. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I don't think the GNU tool has any built-in support for it, but there's this: https://github.com/a8m/envsubst#imposing-restrictions

Comment: `envsubst -no-unset` is seems that we want, but it is not original GNU gettext implementation, it is new implementation written in Golang.

Comment: Where can we get this new Golang version of `envsubst`?

Comment: @muru linked to the github project in their comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ideal, in that it doesn't alter the behaviour of `envsubst` as requested, but it is able to identify unset variables.  The user must ensure that the delimiter `EOF` does not appear in the text.  If it does, then choose a different delimiter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

msg="$( printf 'cat << EOF\n%s\nEOF\n' "$(cat)" )"

bash -u <<< "$msg"
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh < message.txt || echo fail
bash: line 1: LOCATION: unbound variable
fail
$ LOCATION=World ./test.sh < message.txt || echo fail
bash: line 1: PERSON: unbound variable
fail
$ LOCATION=World PERSON=Ralph ./test.sh < message.txt || echo fail
Hello, World! You too, Ralph ;)
```

Here is a lengthier version which will list all the unset variables in one go, instead of disclosing them one at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

check_vars() {

# pass a list of variable names on stdin, one to a line

rc=0

while read v
do
        if [[ ! "${!v}" ]]
        then
                printf '%s\n' "$v"
                rc=1
        fi
done

return $rc

}

envsubst -v "$(cat)" | check_vars
```

This version will output a list of unset (or null) variables, one to a line, and exit with 0 if and only if the list is empty.

Output:

```
$ ./test2.sh < message.txt || echo fail
LOCATION
PERSON
fail
$ PERSON=Ralph ./test2.sh < message.txt || echo fail
LOCATION
fail
$ LOCATION=World ./test2.sh < message.txt || echo fail
PERSON
fail
$ LOCATION=World PERSON=Ralph ./test2.sh < message.txt || echo fail
$
```

Comment: Changing `envsubst` was not a hard requirement. This simple script reliably detects unset variables, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @ixe013.  I expanded the answer to include a version which lists all the undefined variables, instead of only the first one that is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily to the equivalent in `perl` where you can exit with an error if the env var is not defined:

```
perl -pe 's{\$(?|\{(\w+)\}|(\w+))}{$ENV{$1} // die "$& not defined\n"}ge'
```